# why does my a-link in aframe make the entire scene a hyperlink? I just want the portal itself to be a hyperlink

Tags: aframe

Here is the project page (live example): https://aframe101.glitch.me

Here is the code: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/aframe101

When I add in the a-link element:

```
<!--        INTERACTION PORTAL-->
      <a-link
        href="https://activereplica.com/Cn8Uifp/open-house-room-b"
        position="0 1 -2"
        title="My Homepage"
        image="https://cdn.glitch.com/ef233944-f592-4f96-a70c-01d0c5ce72e3%2FGevurah%20Title%20Card.JPG?v=1606935089024"
        on="click"
      ></a-link>
```

Anywhere I click on my screen sends me to another website.

I just want to navigate to another website if I click on the portal itself. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in 1.1.0 portals are no longer supported; its just changed to a link property.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> and look at the boxing link area

Comment: nothing looks unusual about it in the inspector; however, if I make it really small, then when I click the background of the scene, I don't accidentally navigate to another page; so, I think that for some reason its area of activation is much larger than the actual size of the object...

Comment: actually just looked at it again, and the box around the portal is huge... I'm guessing this is what is making its activation be messed up, not sure how to fix it, and this seems weird for what is supposed to be a core basic component